# Question about Power supply for Raspberry Pi Zero W V1.1

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero-w

I recently got a Raspberry Pi Zero W V1.1 as a gift....and I'm a bit confused about the power requirements for it. I have a 5V~2A mobile-charger and a 5V~1A mobile charger. Can I use any one of the two chargers I mentioned as a power supply for my Raspberry Pi or should I buy a new one???? If I should....Then please do specify what should be the voltage and current ratings for the new one.

Comment: Hello and welcome. The Pi Zero W should do fine with any of those two power supplies (as long as they stay in their listed spec for currents less than rated). Mind additional peripherals (mouse, keyboard, ... what-not-else) when considering the power rating of the supply though.

Comment: So....I can use both of them.....Alright...Thanks for the help...!!!!!!